# NetFlow Collector Agent

Tags: python, networking, collections, libraries, netflow

I have a problem with my python code that is about a Netflow collector agent. I run this code in virtual machine and must collects data from netflow agent that is a router which emulate in Gns3. My topology is correct and my devices can ping each other. But this application doesn't work.

```
from netflow import collector
import time

# Define the port to listen on for NetFlow data records
port = 2055
host = '192.168.10.2'
# Define the default time interval (in seconds)
default_time_interval = 1800 # 30 minutes

# Get the time interval from the user (in seconds)
time_interval = input("Enter the time interval (in seconds), or press Enter to use the default value of 30 minutes: ")

# Use the default time interval if the user does not enter a value
if time_interval == '':
    time_interval = default_time_interval
else:
    time_interval = int(time_interval)

# Create a FlowCollector object to listen for NetFlow data records
collector = collector.get_export_packets(host,port)

# Initialize the total bytes received and sent to 0
total_bytes_received = 0
total_bytes_sent = 0

# Initialize a dictionary to store the IP addresses and their corresponding byte counts
ip_bytes_dict = {}

# Initialize the start time for the current time interval
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    # Check if the current time interval has elapsed
    if time.time() - start_time > time_interval:
        # Display the total bytes received and sent for the previous time interval
        print(f'Total bytes received: {total_bytes_received}, Total bytes sent: {total_bytes_sent}')

        # Find the IP addresses that have received traffic in the previous time interval
        ip_list = [ip for ip, bytes in ip_bytes_dict.items() if bytes > 0]

        # Display the IP addresses that have received traffic in the previous time interval
        print(f'IP addresses that have received traffic: {ip_list}')

        # Reset the total bytes received and sent to 0
        total_bytes_received = 0
        total_bytes_sent = 0

        # Reset the byte counts for each IP address in the dictionary to 0
        for ip in ip_bytes_dict:
            ip_bytes_dict[ip] = 0

        # Set the start time for the next time interval
        start_time = time.time()

    # Receive NetFlow data records from the agent
    for data_record in collector:
        # Extract the source and destination IP addresses and bytes transferred
        src_ip = data_record.src_ip
        dst_ip = data_record.dst_ip
        bytes = data_record.bytes

        # Check if the source IP address is within the local network
        if src_ip.startswith('192.168.10.'):
            # This is incoming traffic
            total_bytes_received += bytes
            # Update the byte count for the source IP address in the dictionary
        if src_ip in ip_bytes_dict:
            ip_bytes_dict[src_ip] += bytes
        else: ip_bytes_dict[src_ip] = bytes
        # Check if the destination IP address is within the local network
        if dst_ip.startswith('192.168.10.'):
           # This is outgoing traffic
           total_bytes_sent += bytes
        # Update the byte count for the destination IP address in the dictionary
        if dst_ip in ip_bytes_dict:
            ip_bytes_dict[dst_ip] += bytes
        else:
            ip_bytes_dict[dst_ip] = bytes

# Prompt the user to select an IP address
selected_ip = input("Enter the IP address to view its traffic, or press Enter to continue: ")

# Check if the user entered a valid IP address that received traffic in the previous time interval
if selected_ip in ip_bytes_dict and ip_bytes_dict[selected_ip] > 0:
    # Calculate the amount of traffic received and sent to the selected IP address in the previous time interval
    received_bytes = 0
    sent_bytes = 0
    for ip, bytes in ip_bytes_dict.items():
        if ip == selected_ip:
            received_bytes += bytes
        elif ip.startswith('192.168.10.'):
            sent_bytes += bytes
    # Display the amount of traffic received and sent to the selected IP address
    print(f'Traffic received from {selected_ip}: {received_bytes} bytes')
    print(f'Traffic sent to {selected_ip}: {sent_bytes} bytes')
else:
    # If the selected IP address did not receive traffic in the previous time interval or is not in the dictionary, display an error message
    print(f'Error: {selected_ip} did not receive traffic in the previous time interval.')
```

I get these errors:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\98915\Desktop\netflow collector.py.txt", line 57, in <module>
    for data_record in collector:
  File "C:\Users\98915\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\netflow\collector.py", line 182, in get_export_packets
    listener = ThreadedNetFlowListener(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\98915\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\netflow\collector.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.server = QueuingUDPListener((host, port), self.input)
  File "C:\Users\98915\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\netflow\collector.py", line 60, in __init__
    super().__init__(interface, QueuingRequestHandler)
  File "C:\Users\98915\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\98915\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`
```

Thanks.

I want to resolve the errors.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what the value of `self.server_address` is.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).